# Add column to dataframe to show if an element in that row is in a certain list in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe `df` (tibble in my case) in R and several files in a given directory which have a loose correspondence with the elements of one of the columns in `df`.  I want to track which rows in `df` correspond to these files by adding a column `has_file`.

Here's what I've tried.

```
# SETUP
dir.create("temp")
setwd("temp")
LETTERS[1:4] %>% 
  str_c(., ".png") %>% 
  file.create()

df <- tibble(x = LETTERS[3:6])

file_list <- list.files()

# ATTEMPT
df %>% 
  mutate(
    has_file = file_list %>% 
      str_remove(".png") %>% 
      is.element(x, .) %>% 
      any()
  )

# RESULT
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x     has_file
  <chr> <lgl>   
1 C     TRUE    
2 D     TRUE    
3 E     TRUE    
4 F     TRUE
```

I would expect that only the rows with C and D get values of TRUE for `has_file`, but E and F do as well.

What is happening here, and how may I generate this correspondence in a column?

(Tidyverse solution preferred.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to add `rowwise` at the top because the `any` is going to do the evaluation on the whole column and as there are already two `TRUE` elements, `any` returns TRUE from that row to fill up the whole column.  With `rowwise`, there is no need for `any` as `is.element` returns a single TRUE/FALSE per each element of 'x' column

```
df %>% 
 rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    has_file = file_list %>% 
      str_remove(".png") %>% 
      is.element(x, .)) %>%  
  ungroup
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x     has_file
  <chr> <lgl>   
1 C     TRUE    
2 D     TRUE    
3 E     FALSE   
4 F     FALSE
```

i.e. check the difference after adding the `any`

```
> is.element(df$x,  LETTERS[1:4])
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> any(is.element(df$x,  LETTERS[1:4]))
[1] TRUE
```

---

We may also use `map` to do this

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(has_file = map_lgl(x, ~ file_list %>% 
                str_remove(".png") %>% 
                is.element(.x, .)))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x     has_file
  <chr> <lgl>   
1 C     TRUE    
2 D     TRUE    
3 E     FALSE   
4 F     FALSE
```

---

Or if we want to use vectorized option, instead of using `is.element`, do the `%in%` directly

```
df %>% 
   mutate(has_file = x %in% str_remove(file_list, ".png"))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x     has_file
  <chr> <lgl>   
1 C     TRUE    
2 D     TRUE    
3 E     FALSE   
4 F     FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun.  The first approach works for my actual data as well; I haven't confirmed yet the `map` solution but that looks good too.  In my case, it's taking quite a while.  Do you have a sense about which approach may be more efficient computationally?

Comment: @RobCreel I would say `map` would be faster` compared to `rowwise`

Comment: @RobCreel For your case vectorized option is `df %>% mutate(has_file = x %in% str_remove(file_list, ".png"))`

Comment: @RobCreel Please check the updated code.  it should be way faster than the other two